# Windows 10 kiosk mode, no Apps available

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-universal, kiosk

I tried to install *Windows 10* kiosk mode for the user "**kiosk**" without success, the assigned access app selection list is empty.

Here is what I have done: I used the "**administrator**" account and created an *Universal Windows App* with *Visual Studio 2015* (I just compiled the empty project, I do not added code). I built an App package and installed the app from/for the "kiosk" account.

Back in the "**administrator**" account, I tried to set up the assigned access. I added the user "**kiosk**" and followed the assigned access settings. But, there is no App in the selection for the account "kiosk".

I also switched the "**kiosk**" account to an administrator account, but the list of Apps is still empty. Log in and log out still did not solved the problem.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never use windows native koisk mode - it is useless. Best solution is shell replacing. Just build windows forms application and use it as shell. Not windows store app. Here the instruction:

- Create user for kiosk mode:

  ```
  net user kiosk /ADD
  ```
- Set next registry key for this user as path to your application (you need to login as kiosk user and run script OR load this user registry in regedit):

Windows XP/7/10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Windows 8:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Autologin for kiosk user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] 
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="kiosk"
"DefaultDomainName"="<place here pc hostname>"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

*[Option]* If you need to disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, then use this registry key value ("") or you can place there own application:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
"Debugger"="\"\""
```

Comment: how to do it with Windows 10? Not able to find HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Comment: Just create it.

Comment: Nothing happens after adding the registry. I don't even get an error code.

Comment: this isnt helpful for windows 10 and greater. can you edit for this?

Comment: Yep, will do soon.

Comment: @DannyJames, 
Fixed: Windows 10 has same key as XP and 7: just tested in W10 22H2 version - it works.